# How to print to Zebra printer with DirectIO instead of PrintNormal?

Tags: javascript, activex, zebra-printers

Does anyone know how to use DirectIO instead of PrintNormal for the following javascript?

```
printer.Open("zebraprinter");
printer.ClaimDevice(1000);
printer.DeviceEnabled = true;
printer.PrintNormal(2, "^XA");
printer.PrintNormal(2, "^LH0,0");
printer.PrintNormal(2, "^FO100,100^ASI^FDTest^FS");
printer.PrintNormal(2, "^XZ");
printer.MarkFeed(3);
printer.DeviceEnabled = false;
printer.ReleaseDevice();
printer.Close();
```

Comment: Just curious but what is PrintNormal??  Is this an ActiveX control?  If so where can you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the C# (Microsoft POS for .Net) code:

```
PosExplorer ex = new PosExplorer();
DeviceInfo d = ex.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, "zebraprinter");
PosPrinter printer = (PosPrinter)ex.CreateInstance(d);

printer.Open();
printer.Claim(1000);
printer.DeviceEnabled = true;

printer.DirectIO(0, 0, "^XA");
printer.DirectIO(0, 0, "^LH0,0");
printer.DirectIO(0, 0, "^FO100,100^ASI^FDTest^FS");
printer.DirectIO(0, 0, "^XZ");

printer.DirectIO(0, 0, "^MFN,F");

printer.DeviceEnabled = false;
printer.Release();
printer.Close();
```

Note that I don't have tested above code, but the code should be near of that what you want.